# Need to make a twitter share button that shares the random quote from a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I've made a random quote generator for FreeCodeCamp. I placed the twitter button in the HTML, but I don't know how to get it to tweet the quote that is generated on the page. I am lost!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
<div id="quote">
 Get Betrand Russelled
   </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button id="main" class="btn btn-lg" onclick="quoteGen()" value="">

<b>Russell Me</b>

</button>

    </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<button class="btn btn-lg" id="tweet">

  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-  show-count="false" data-size="large">Tweet</a>

<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">

</script>
</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
    var array="quote,quote2,quote3"
     var randomIndex= Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
      var randomElement = array[randomIndex];
       response_text.innerHTML=randomElement;

  return true

  }
```

Please help me!!!!! I feel so alone

Answer (score 1):

your array is a string, you should do this:

```
var array = ["quote", "quote2", "quote3"];
```